# Conditional probability Measure

Tags: probability

Each datum can have three features:

1. A marker = $\{X, \neg X\}$
2. A rating based on EQ1 = $\{1, 2, ..., 10\}$
3. A rating based on EQ2 = $\{1, 2, ..., 10\}$

I have the following knowledge about the data set:

- The whole data-set consists of $190000$ entries.
- 180087 have a rating based on EQ1
- 118088 have a rating based on EQ2
- 106754 have both ratings
- There is a total of 32000 marked ones. However, I do not not which.

I have a sample space of 16000 objects which are marked and I know the ratings of EQ1 and EQ2, if they have one.

What I'm trying to answer: **Given a object with a rating based on one of both EQ, what is the probability that it is marked?**

My current approach is as follows:

For each EQ:

- Take all objects of the sample space that have a rating of EQ
- Group the objects by rating and calculate the share each group has
- Multiply each group share by the total marked ones (32000) to estimate the number of marked objects in each group
- Divide each group by the number of total objects in that group taken from the whole data-set.

Or as formula for one group:
$P(X | EQ1) = \frac{G_1*32000}{TG_1}$
with $G_1 = \frac{\{g \in \Omega|eq1(g)=1\}}{|\Omega|}$ and $TG_1 = \{x \in T|eq1(x)=1\}$ and T = The whole data-set

My Question is: Do I need to account for the fact that not all objects have EQ1 and EQ2 and that each subset is different in size? My feeling is telling me that I have to, but I do not know how, as I can not differentiate all marked ones.

Comment: What do you mean by "group-wiste" ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I was referring to the fact that I want to calculate the probability for the two subsets. However, it may not add information and I therefore edited the title.

Comment: Maybe you meant group**wise** ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes, indeed!